# The meaning(s) of "for"

Tags: word-meaning, for

I wonder what the meaning(s) of "for"s in the following sentences/phrases are.

1. I have a lot of homework for tomorrow.
2. I have a lot of homework for English.
3. The schedule for next week.
4. What are we going to do for our music history class?
5. To wait for someone.
6. Keep it for me.
7. I got the square root of 3 for problem number 6.

It really confuses me. Can you explain it to me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that it provides context. If you let left it off it would beg a question to provide more information. Prepositions in languages though have a brilliant capability for inventing the rules as they go along.
1 and 3 you have (noun) for (time period). Here it qualifies the time it applies to (no one cares when hoework is given, only its due date matters)
2 (noun) for (noun). The second qualifies the first. "English homework" would do just as good.
4-6 are a bit different. It is a verb being qualified. In 5 "for" is used as wait takes a time period as an object when not using a preposition (wait half an hour). Here it is a thing waited for. 6 though is interesting as it changes the meaning of the verb more than others.

There are many more examples that will create even more confusion:
I'm done with this place for good.
What is the therefore there for?
The stackexchange community is here for you.

Comment: Thank you. Is it okay to say "this address is for the hotel where we will stay"? If yes, what does "for" mean here?

Comment: Yes, but it can be a bit vague. If it is the hotel's address then you would usually say "this is the address of the hotel where..." "for" could be taken as the address being a different one that you want the person to give to the hotel (in this case there should be some pre-existing context that someone from the hotel asked for an address)